# Flutter: error Xcode: command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I tried to run flutter after updating to the newest stable version

```
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcodes output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/56/fc0b38hx7dv7ldxkbs9flh_m0000gn/T/flutter_tools.sDq2W5/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirGNvLvF/temporary_xcresult_bundle

    /usr/local/Caskroom/flutter/2.5.2/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/platform-3.0.0/lib/src/interface/local_platform.dart:46:19: Error: Member not
    found: 'packageRoot'.
          io.Platform.packageRoot; // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel

    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/56/fc0b38hx7dv7ldxkbs9flh_m0000gn/T/flutter_tools.sDq2W5/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirGNvLvF/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro.
```

I've tried `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` but that isn't the fix. Anyone any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried `flutter pub cache repair`?

Comment: Yes I tried that, but it isn't the fix. Have you any other idea?

Comment: Check this may help : https://stackoverflow.com/a/75947102/6667442

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As i see you are currently using **flutter 2.5.2** which is newest,So Update you flutter SDK  by running command

```
flutter upgrade
```

Then  Upgrade the current package's dependencies to latest versions by running command

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

Go to iOS folder of the project run

```
pod init
```

and

```
pod install
```

I hope this solution solve your problem.

Please up the vote if this answer help you.

Comment: This answer is good way to start. For me it wasn't a complete fix.

Migrate for Android is needed also:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects

Comment: flutter version upgrade solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

I spent **way** too much time on this issue.

For me the problem was related to the Flutter cache and running the following command resolved the issue:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

The solution made sense to me when I noticed a plugin trying to reference `[flutter-sdk-path]/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/screens.dart`--which did not exist in my Flutter SDK.

Ref: [Update flutter dependencies in /.pub-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399209/update-flutter-dependencies-in-pub-cache/59219256#59219256)

Guys, sometimes it better to just **GO TO SLEEP**! It helps a great deal to have fresh eyes looking at a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem on **Xcode 14** with me and This solution worked for me as well

Update the following code in -frameworks.sh files to add the -f flag to calls to readlink. In other words

```
source="$(readlink "${source}")"

 with

source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

if you have Podfile in iOS folder

Go to iOS folder of the project

run

`flutter clean`

and

`flutter pub get`

and

`pod update`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer). Especially information about what those commands do, so others won't run commands without thinking about them. Additionally `pod update` might not always be the right tool, so explaining why use `pod update` instead of `pod install` would be beneficial.