# GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:10:9: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I am trying to run my flutter app in iOS emulator, but I got error saying `'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found`. I have tried multiple solutions like pod clean and reinstalling pods.

flutter version:- 2.10.4
xcode version:- 13.3.1 (13E500a)

[image]

[image]

Comment: try to do flutter clean. flutter pub get and cd ios and then pod install and pod update and run again. First clear Derived data then perform these steps.

Comment: try this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64993852/17079652. it worked for me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70708891/16606510 Check this.

Comment: Hi, i have tried all of these solution, it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tried a lot of Solution, non of them work for me, so I manually need to regenerate iOS Directory and configure everything in iOS.
Here are the following commands:-

```
1. rm -rf ios/
2. flutter create .
```

Answer (score 1):

My case was that I accidentaly removed default "Run Script" from my Targets/Runner/Build Phases
[image: Targets/Runner/Build Phases]

Check if your "Run Script" exists between "Check Pods Manifest.lock" and "Compile Sources" with the script:

```bash
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build
```

Comment: It's my case. Thx.