# Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -5/Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code error when archiving Xcode flutter app

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm fairly new to stack overflow so if you need some more information, just add a comment or something.

I have been working on a fluter app for a while now. I am trying to get the app on the apple store, but when I tried archiving the app in Xcode, I get the error:
"Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -5
Failed to package /Users/brightli/Documents/App.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

I haven't really been able to find any solutions yet. I have a feeling this may have something to do with the pods or podfile.

I'm not sure what code I should share for this, so if you want to try and answer the question but need some files, I can edit the question.

Comment: Try this.https://stackoverflow.com/a/70708891/16606510

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your project from an iCloud location. Try moving the entire project under your user directory.

Then go into Android Studios, click the file, select open, and then find your project inside the new non-iCloud location, and it should run with no problems.