# Flutter : Could not build the precompiled application for the device. Error launching application on iPhone

Tags: ios, flutter, compiler-errors

I can't run my flutter project on an IOS device.

This is what I got after flutter run. I can't understand why. Please have a look at the error below and tell me how to fix this.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team
in Xcode project: L24VC6F98D
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            8,2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2020-09-18 11:56:14.934 xcodebuild[29414:155421] warning:  The file reference
    for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h"
    is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and
    "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
    membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets
    will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than
    one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2020-09-18 11:56:14.934 xcodebuild[29414:155421] warning:  The file reference
    for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h" is a member
    of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this
    indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will
    be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a
    reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
    reference to the same path.
    2020-09-18 11:56:14.934 xcodebuild[29414:155421] warning:  The file reference
    for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h" is a
    member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController");
    this indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups
    will be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want
    a reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
    reference to the same path.
    2020-09-18 11:56:14.934 xcodebuild[29414:155421] warning:  The file reference
    for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h" is a member of
    multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this
    indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will
    be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a
    reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
    reference to the same path.
    2020-09-18 11:56:14.934 xcodebuild[29414:155421] warning:  The file reference
    for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h" is a member of
    multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this
    indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will
    be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a
    reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
    reference to the same path.
    2020-09-18 11:56:14.934 xcodebuild[29414:155421] warning:  The file reference
    for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h" is a member of
    multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this
    indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will
    be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a
    reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
    reference to the same path.
    2020-09-18 11:56:14.934 xcodebuild[29414:155421] warning:  The file reference
    for "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h" is a member of
    multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and "TOCropViewController"); this
    indicates a malformed project.  Only the membership in one of the groups will
    be preserved (but membership in targets will be unaffected).  If you want a
    reference to the same file in more than one group, please add another
    reference to the same path.
    2020-09-18 11:56:14.934 xcodebuild[29414:155421] warning:  The file reference
    for
    "Objective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h"
    is a member of multiple groups ("TOCropViewController" and
    "TOCropViewController"); this indicates a malformed project.  Only the
    membership in one of the groups will be preserved (but membership in targets
    will be unaffected).  If you want a reference to the same file in more than
    one group, please add another reference to the same path.
    2020-09-18 11:56:14.978 xcodebuild[29414:155477]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from
    d94358f0937915cc1dbf618d6c7be90be0612766 was NULL
    2020-09-18 11:56:15.129 xcodebuild[29414:155486]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from
    d94358f0937915cc1dbf618d6c7be90be0612766 was NULL
    2020-09-18 11:56:15.129 xcodebuild[29414:155486]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from
    d94358f0937915cc1dbf618d6c7be90be0612766 was NULL
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    /Users/punreachrany/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/kakao
    _flutter_sdk-0.4.2/ios/Classes/SwiftKakaoFlutterSdkPlugin.swift:103:82: error:
    cannot convert value of type 'Error' to specified type
    'ASWebAuthenticationSessionError.Code'
                        if case ASWebAuthenticationSessionError.Code.canceledLogin
                        = err {
                                                                                     ^~~
    /Users/punreachrany/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/kakao
    _flutter_sdk-0.4.2/ios/Classes/SwiftKakaoFlutterSdkPlugin.swift:108:72: error:
    cannot convert value of type 'Error' to specified type
    'SFAuthenticationError.Code'
                        if case SFAuthenticationError.Code.canceledLogin = err {
                                                                           ^~~
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'shared_preferences' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'path_provider' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'onesignal_flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'abseil' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'package_info' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'esys_flutter_share' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'PromisesObjC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
    /Users/punreachrany/Desktop/Flutter/PhotoEarn/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Ob
    jective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOActivityCroppedImageProvider.h (in
    target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
    /Users/punreachrany/Desktop/Flutter/PhotoEarn/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Ob
    jective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropOverlayView.h (in target
    'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
    /Users/punreachrany/Desktop/Flutter/PhotoEarn/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Ob
    jective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCroppedImageAttributes.h (in target
    'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
    /Users/punreachrany/Desktop/Flutter/PhotoEarn/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Ob
    jective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropScrollView.h (in target
    'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
    /Users/punreachrany/Desktop/Flutter/PhotoEarn/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Ob
    jective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropToolbar.h (in target
    'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
    /Users/punreachrany/Desktop/Flutter/PhotoEarn/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Ob
    jective-C/TOCropViewController/Views/TOCropView.h (in target
    'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
    /Users/punreachrany/Desktop/Flutter/PhotoEarn/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Ob
    jective-C/TOCropViewController/TOCropViewController.h (in target
    'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Skipping duplicate build file in Copy Headers build phase:
    /Users/punreachrany/Desktop/Flutter/PhotoEarn/ios/Pods/TOCropViewController/Ob
    jective-C/TOCropViewController/Models/TOCropViewControllerTransitioning.h (in
    target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'nanopb' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'gRPC-C++-gRPCCertificates-Cpp' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'GoogleDataTransport' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'GTMSessionFetcher' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'FBSDKCoreKit' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'BoringSSL-GRPC' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'BSImageView' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'BSGridCollectionViewLayout' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'GoogleUtilities' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'GoogleDataTransportCCTSupport' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'FBSDKLoginKit' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'image_cropper' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'GoogleAppMeasurement' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'gRPC-C++' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'OneSignal-iOS10.0' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'Flutter' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'gRPC-Core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'FirebaseFirestore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'FirebaseAuthInterop' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'firebase_auth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'FirebaseCore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'firebase_core' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'firebase_database' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'cloud_firestore' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'FirebaseAnalytics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'FirebaseInstallations' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnosticsInterop' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'FirebaseAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'FirebaseDatabase' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'OneSignal-iOS11.0' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'FirebaseStorage' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'FirebaseCoreDiagnostics' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'firebase_storage' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0,
    but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.0.99. (in
    target 'Firebase' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone.
```

What can I do to fix this problem? Please give me a command line or sth. Please help me. I am looking forward to hearing from you. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to simulate it immediately rather than taking care of the IDE issue generally, go to Tools -> Flutter -> Open iOS module in Xcode. But for a further solution, do a Flutter Clean, and remove the simulator from Xcode -> Window -> Devices and Simulators -> Simulators -> right click on your iOS simulator and click delete. Then add a new simulator from the bottom left corner “+” button in the same Devices and Simulators page you are on. Re run your app in flutter and it should be working.

Comment: Do you also know how to fix this with a connected device?

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me was a combination of 4 steps:

**Step 1, modify Podfile**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.1'
```

and add the following (iOS platform must match):

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '12.1'
    end
  end
end
```

**Step 2, switch Flutter channel to master and upgrade Flutter**

```
$ flutter channel master
$ flutter upgrade
```

**Step 3, Upgrade dependencies**

```
$ flutter pub upgrade
```

**Step 4, clean and build**

```
$ flutter clean
$ flutter build ios
```

Comment: I had this problem with Flutter version 3.10.0. And the answer was the solution. The only different thing I did was to skip step 2.

Answer (score 8):

I got this issue today and this is how i fixed:

1. run `flutter clean`
2. Restart system
3. Restart ios device

Comment: what do you consider by "system"?

Comment: Your laptop or computer.

Comment: Thus worked for me - particularly restarting my Mac. Other answers might suggest to mark the "For install builds only" option - that actually broke things for me, it started complaining about not finding header files - e.g., Flutter.h. So yeah, at least in my case I didn't do that. By the way, the issue started to happen after some update in my Mac.

Comment: It did not work for me

Comment: I was really hesitant to try this, but surprisingly it worked.  After each step, I tried to build the app, but it failed until step 3.  Will try in reverse sometime.

Comment: `flutter clean` is suffice.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, I also got into this after upgrading to ios 14.
So, first, add this to you podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      # drop deployment target so it works with ios14
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET
    end
  end
end
```

and also run: `flutter upgrade`

For me, these 2 things fixed the problem.

Comment: It didn't work for me. Do you have any reference regarding this issue?

Comment: ok, one more thing: edit your `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and update the `IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` to be `9.0` (it should appear 3 times in this file). Replace them all.

Comment: Oh man... well, time to wait for ios 15 then :-) Sorry to hear that. Ok, what about completely updating your podfile with: `rm -rf ios/Podfile.lock; pod repo update` and then a `flutter clean`?

Comment: Any luck there? (I assume you also do a proper `flutter clean` before trying these fixes)

Comment: You have a quote missing in your code snippet :) Plus for the latest flutter you need to add `config.build_settings.delete` to the existing `post_install do |installer|` section in that file as they don't support two post_install sections. Otherwise, it worked for me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

If you previously followed the FlutterFire steps here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview#improve-ios-build-times then it is time to disable the pre-compiled version of Firestore stuff and let Xcode compile it from scratch.

In the file `ios/Podfile` comment this line:

```
# pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '6.26.0'
```

Run your app and it should work now.

Comment: Useless in this context and not relevant.

Comment: It's Dec 1st 2023 and this resolved my issue so it does appear to be relevant to developers who are using Firebase Firestore invertase precompiled binaries. I was on Firestore 10.16.0 and just updated to 10.18.0 which broke my build. Switching back to the regular pod resolved my build issue.

Answer (score 3):

You will also get this error, if the iOS device is not registered with apple for development.

Answer (score 2):

Run this command in the ios folder it works for me

```
pod repo update
```

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all of the above solutions. Noting works for me. Here is the exact solution that worked for me.

**Solution**:
To fix this issue, you can follow these steps:

1. Open Xcode and load your iOS project.
2. In the Xcode project navigator, locate the "Runner" folder within your iOS project.
3. Click on "Runner" to select it.
4. Open the "Build Settings" tab for the "Runner" target.
5. In the search bar, type 'User Script Sandboxing.'
6. You'll find an option named "User Script Sandboxing." Change the value from 'Yes' to 'No.'
7. Save your changes.

**Why This Works:**
This issue is related to the security settings for scripts during the build process. Changing the "User Script Sandboxing" option to 'No' disables the sandboxing for user scripts, allowing Flutter to write the necessary files without encountering permission issues.

Comment: Thank you for providing your solution. this worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem. IOS logs are not correctly described like Android. So try to follow the instruction below its work for me.

1. Run current code in Android Emulator. I have found that in Android logs show some of my dependencies syntaxes were deprecated (For me is flutter_svg)
2. I have changed the version of the flutter_svg version to ^0.19.0. You need to fix all the deprecated syntax of your run log.
3. Try to run in Android Emulator now it's work for me.
4. Try to run in IOS Emulator. (First time it's not working so I close IDE and reopen again and run) In this case `flutter clean` should sort your problem.

This works for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

A coworker told me to run:

```
flutter clean
```

then:

```
flutter pub get
```

after that it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I'm using xcode 13.2.1 and iOS 15.7.3.
Basically, the xcode not support iOS 15.7.3 by default.
So I've had to download the supporting file from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71667372) according to [this acticle](https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport/issues/144)