# Why am I getting an error like this in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am using firebase with flutter, but the build fails with the following error.

The code works on Android, but fails on IOS. And I am having a trouble resolving the issue by just looking at the error log.

I am suspecting that something went wrong during the process of installing SDK on XCODE, but I am not certain about this.

Could someone please help me resolve the error?

Thanks in advance!

```
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Error (Xcode): redefinition of module 'Firebase'
/Users/madol.eeee/project/travelingFlutter/ios/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources/module.modulemap:0:7
Error (Xcode): could not build module 'ObjectiveC'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/usr/include/os/object.h:110:8

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'os_object'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:62:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'os_object'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/usr/include/os/workgroup_base.h:18:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'Dispatch'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFStream.h:19:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:5:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Headers/SecBase.h:27:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Headers/CFNetwork.h:17:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'Foundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIKit.h:7:8

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGBase.h:11:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreGraphics'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Headers/CoreImageDefines.h:16:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Headers/CVBase.h:29:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOSurface.framework/Headers/IOSurfaceBase.h:35:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'Foundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/Headers/EAGL.h:7:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'Foundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Headers/MTLTypes.h:7:8

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Headers/ImageIOBase.h:15:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Headers/CTFontTraits.h:13:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Headers/CABase.h:15:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'Foundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/Headers/NSFileProviderDomain.h:7:8

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'Foundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UserNotifications.framework/Headers/NSString+UserNotifications.h:7:8

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'UIKit'
/Users/madol.eeee/project/travelingFlutter/build/ios/Debug-iphoneos/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterAppDelegate.h:7:8

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/Headers/CMBase.h:166:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudioTypes.framework/Headers/CoreAudioBaseTypes.h:17:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'CoreAudioTypes'
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Headers/CoreAudioTypes.h:3:9

Error (Xcode): could not build module 'Flutter'
/Users/madol.eeee/project/travelingFlutter/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h:9:8

Error (Xcode): failed to emit precompiled header '/Users/madol.eeee/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dpzhbuurutkxknelzflupakbyrqz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/Runner-Bridging-Header-swift_QKNU0R6E1AJH-clang_2AA7G5TQAG0QG.pch' for bridging header '/Users/madol.eeee/project/travelingFlutter/ios/Runner/Runner-Bridging-Header.h'


Error launching application on 아이폰11.
```

Comment: Please see this link it has solution of your problem
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63948739/flutter-could-not-build-the-precompiled-application-for-the-device-error-laun

Comment: Please try the Flutter clean process as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64402162/10737626

Comment: It's a real device, not a simulator, can I apply the same?