# Xcode 14.3 build error after iOS 16.4 update: libarclite_iphoneos.a not found, linker command failed

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I recently updated my iPhone to iOS 16.4 and Xcode to version 13.4. Since the update, I'm encountering an error while trying to build my iOS application in Xcode. The error message is as follows:

`Could not build the precompiled application for the device. Error (Xcode): File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphoneos.a Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

This issue started happening after updating to iOS 16.4 and Xcode 13.4.

I tried:

1. run flutter clean
2. Restart system
3. Restart ios device

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68651798

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I wasn't able to build for 16.4 after upgrading iOS on my phone, too. Since Xcode did not support 16.4, yet.

Today a new version of Xcode was released. I guess it will fix this issue.

However, I was able to solve this by doing the following:

Download the Xcode release candidate 3 (RC3) from the Apple Developer web site and extract it. You then have to right click on the extracted app and select »show package contents«. You then need to copy the files from `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/16.4` to `Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport` within your currently installed version of Xcode.

[image]

As mentioned above, the new release will probably fix this, but this workaround might be useful for future iOS updates.

*UPDATE*:

The latest version of Xcode (14.3) introduced the same issue for me. I was able to fixe the issue by modifying my `ios/Podfile` to set the level for deployment targets to 11.0.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end

  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
            target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I had the same issue, changing the Podfile was the solution for me. Thanks :)

Comment: I have implemented this solution and now it build the app successfully but after launch it crashes. I was not facing this issue before updating. Xcode 14.3 and iOS 16.4 . Any idea on how to solve it?