# Xcode error: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code (Showing Recent Errors Only)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter, xcode12

I created an app in flutter and used a stateless widget to just display some Information on the screen. The app installed and worked as expected on an android device. But when I wanted to deploy it on an iOS device I opened Xcode, signed using my developer profile and selected the recommended settings. Then I got an error that said

```
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

`Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-hfjtuvhggwzrrceitthqbpzcpuss/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Runner.build/Script-9740EEB61CF901F6004384FC.sh`

I think this is an issue pertaining to Xcode itself. Before posting here I also googled the issue and tried various other methods but in vain.

[Error from the logs[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlmxe.jpg)
I will be happy to share more pictures of errors from the console which may help solve the error further

Comment: did you try answers for this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57919267/command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-while-trying-to-add

Comment: Hi, I did try that. But when I selected 'For Install Builds only' the build succeeded but then I got an error saying the app could not be installed. I checked in the settings>General tab of my iPhone if there was any request under device Management but no. There was nothing there

Comment: Hi again, an update. The app could not be installed because This application’s bundle identifier does not match its code signing identifier. I checked the signing and capabilities and build phases. Still I am getting this error. But the build succeeded. Please help

Comment: @Mol0ko , your suggestion worked. I just checked the box which said For Install Build only in Build phases under run script. Then it installed and worked fine on the simulator/emulator.
Thanks for your suggestion, helped me a lot really