# Flutter - firebase_app_check not working in release mode, how fix it?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-app-check

I using firebase_app_check in my flutter app. And I use AppCheck in Firebase. it turned out to be not easy to set up, there are a lot of "white spots" in the documentation. so in order:

1. I enabled AppCheck on Firebase(for starage and Firestore).
2. I selected "Play Integrity"(so the documentation recommends) as attestation providers.
3. I added plugin firebase_app_check to my app.
   But it not worked. the app(in debug mode) cannot retrieve data from the firestore.
4. Then I added "SafetyNet" as attestation provider. After this app worked(debug mode).
5. I publised my appbundle to Google Play. When I downloaded app from Google Play it not worked(cannot retrieve data from the firestore). I using obfuscation for my appbundle.

Why my app not worked with AppChecker in release mode?
Why "Play Integrity" not worked?
do I have to add code at the platform level? according to this [document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/safetynet-provider)?
like this:

```
 val firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance()
   firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
   SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
 )
```

or is one plugin enough?

How I can fix it?

Comment: Did you add the SHA-256 fingerprint of your app's signing certificate?

Comment: Can you tell more about this?

Comment: Take a look at this and especially step 2: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/safetynet-provider.

Comment: Yes - I used it

Comment: In case of release have you enabled proguard ? if not look into this thread https://github.com/yongjhih/android-proguards/blob/master/google-gms-safetynet-pro/google-gms-safetynet.pro

Comment: Have a look at this github link(https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9178

Comment: Same problem here, I followed the documentation below, but I cant get it to work. Also, I don't understand why we need AppCheck since we already have a google-service.json containing the SHA certificate fingerprint to identify the app to firebase. 
   https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/default-providers?authuser=0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I finally figured this one out, documentation is very scattered, so here is a summary:

**WARNING:** if you want to debug against your firebase backend with AppCheck enabled you have to get a debug token and add it in Firebase every hour or so. Only a physical iOS device can be debugged without this token. For iOS emulator you must first run your app via Xcode and get the token there. This is quite a drawback in AppCheck imo.

**Android Debugging (Device and Simulator):**

1. You have to use `androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug` as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider#android)
2. Then run your app, it wont work, **BUT** look inside the console for the following line: `Enter this debug secret into the allow list in the Firebase Console for your project: 49367303-30f3-4913-a596-...` if you don't see this line: hit Hot Restart.
3. Copy this code and open Firebase Console > App Check > Apps > click the 3 dots behind your Android app > Manage debug tokens, add your token here:
   [image]

**Android Production:**

For production you first have to follow the steps in [1. Set up your Firebase project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider#project-setup). **NOTE** Especially step 3 is very vague:
*Register your apps to use App Check with the Play Integrity provider in the App Check section of the Firebase console. You will need to provide the SHA-256 fingerprint of your app's signing certificate.*
**What they mean is:**

1. In google Play Console under: Release > Setup > App Integrity > App Signing > copy the SHA-256 certificate fingerprint.
2. Add this fingerprint in Firebase console > App Check > Apps > click your Android app > Play integrity
3. Now create a new build and upload it to Play Store.

**iOS**
I got this to work on iOS by following these docs:

1. [1. Set up your Firebase project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/ios/devicecheck-provider#project-setup), follow all the links in that documentation, (which takes you to apple.com and back)
2. for debugging on iOS emulator follow [this documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider)
3. If you encounter build errors in Xcode (like I did), [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57919267/command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code-while-trying-to-add/74659870#74659870)

Comment: What would the world do without you?! Awesome answer!

Comment: I don't know, probably not App Check :-)

Comment: it still doesn't work, throw [firebase_app_check/unknown] p0.l: Error returned from API. code: 403 body: App attestation failed error when running FirebaseAppCheck.instance.getToken(true)

Answer (score 2):

For me, the app check failed on a Flutter app even after I completed all the above steps mentioned by [@Niels](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74654576/10505839). After going through the documentation for [Android Play Integrity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/android/play-integrity-provider#project-setup) in Default providers, I found out that there are additional steps to complete not listed in Flutter's section of the documentation. I was missing point `1.2` in the above link.

I had to go to Play Console App > Release > App Integrity > Integrity API and then link my Firebase/Google Cloud project. After this, all subsequent builds uploaded to the Play Store started working.