# Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'

Tags: xcode, flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-dependencies

I get this error:

> Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
> FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod install
```

Comment: Do you think its tied to a certain date . This error appeared suddenly without making any code changes

Comment: @JayShenawy, its not a specific date. There was a breaking change introduced in an patch update. If you use `^` for any dependency in `pubspec.yaml` (eg. `^4.5.1`), this means that the dependency will auto update to any patch/minor version available. This is why, without changing any code, this error suddenly appeared

Comment: Check my answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74580648/5501242

Answer (score 145):

If you need to maintain the current dependency version, you can add the dependency override to your root `pubspec.yaml` to fix this too.
If you use multiple local packages in your project, this makes it so you don't have to update all your `pubspec.yaml` files

```yaml
dependency_overrides:
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
```

As of 10/6/22, there was an [update with breaking changes](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage/changelog#1100). So you can run the following script to update your dependencies their next major versions.

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

After adding this, run the following commands to update the iOS project's pods

```
cd ios && pod deintegrate
rm -f Podfile.lock
flutter packages get
pod install --repo-update
```

Comment: its really work for me.. after  i update kotlin gradle to 'ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10''

Answer (score 72):

I had the same problem. Some of my plugins were running on older outdated packages and there has been a major version upgrade as mentioned by others. When running `flutter pub upgrade`, it only upgrades to the latest minor version. To fix this, I did the following:

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

to upgrade to the latest supported major-versions. After that, everything worked great!

Please be aware that this may introduce some breaking changes in your code. But here at least, you may be able to fix your code to run on the latest library packages and run your app.

Answer (score 23):

`firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1`

Try adding this package in `pubspec.yaml` to force install 4.5.1,

4.5.2 has major changes, which was being automatically downloaded by `firebase_core`

Answer (score 16):

> I think this solved my futterfire-induced morning problem:
> Hard 4.5.1 dependency... /pubspec.yaml ->

```
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
  firebase_messaging: ^13.0.4 # will satisfy your firebase core things that depend on ^4.5.1
```

Github ref: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9806#issuecomment-1294003289

Comment: Hehe that was my github comment. I guess I should've spent more time on my answer here :)

Answer (score 11):

A breaking changes was done,few hours ago.Try this works.For more info see github issue: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9806

```
firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
firebase_messaging: ^13.0.4 # will satisfy your firebase core things that depend on ^4.5.1
```

Answer (score 10):

I could be wrong about this solution, but there was a [bug introduced](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9806) in some firebase packages because breaking changes were added to a minor/patch. The quick fix for me was to specify the exact version of the firebase_core_platform_interface in my pubspec.yaml:

```
firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
```

After flutter clean this satisfied my packages relying on firebase_core_platform_interface "^4.5.1" and prevented introducing the breaking changes by utilizing 4.5.2 (in this case verifyExtends being renamed verify? whoops).

Answer (score 8):

When it comes to errors that sound like this:

```
Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'
```

Then indeed the issue is related to using older versions of the `firebase_core_platform_interface`. By the time I'm answering this question, the latest version is `4.5.2`:

```
firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.2
```

So the general recommendation is to always use the latest versions.

**Where can you find the newer versions that are released?**

In the official documentation that exists in the link below:

- https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core_platform_interface/versions

**Where should you place it?**

In the `pubspec.yaml` file.

**How to update to the latest version by command line?**

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Answer (score 7):

I did get the same error. Problem seems to be with firebase packages, maybe bug or break in version. You can try any one of below:

```
// Try add this to dependencies section in pubspec.yaml file
firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
```

OR

```
// run this in terminal
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

[Please check this answer as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74596781/4370398)

Answer (score 6):

**Root cause**

You are update or installing only a subset of the Firebase plugins (firebase_core, firebase_analytics,...)

**Solution**

**Solution 1:** (preferred) Updating to the latest version with flutterfire update check the docs here. But it is not easily because your project will have a lot of packages dependencies to each other like flutter version 2 or 3, so on. Anyway, it is long term solution.

**Solution 2:** (Fix to run) You can add to your pubspec.yaml

```
 dependency_overrides:
    firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
```

**Solution 3**: (Fix to run) Update dependencies with this below command line:

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

**Finally**, Run the project again by following stuffs:

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
cd ios && rm -f Podfile.lock
cd ios && pod install --repo-update
flutter run
```

That's it!

Comment: Solution 2 worked for me (know its a momentary solution) but solution 3 didn't solve the problem, at least in my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
flutter run
```

So this error occurred because I was following an old course. I simply went and ran these two commands to solve the issue

Comment: best & easiest solution

Answer (score 5):

Update firebase_cli to latest version

For macOS

```
curl -sL firebase.tools | upgrade=true bash
```

Then activate firebase_cli globally

```
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli
```

Then update flutterfire

```
flutterfire update
```

Then upgrade all flutter packages

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

Also, stay on firebase_core: 2.1.1

Reference : https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9806

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem while using

```
firebase_core: 2.1.0
```

But the problem is solved in

```
firebase_core: 2.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in pubspc.yaml

```
firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.5.1
```

[image]

Then go to pubspec.lock
edit

```
firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.5.2
```

To

```
firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.5.1
```

[image]

Then

Write in terminal

```
flutter clean
```

Then

```
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 1):

If none of the previous solutions works,

**simply change the cache file [firebase_app.dart]** like below,

**FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_var) to FirebaseAppPlatform.verify(_var)**

It works like a charm, if didn't work for you then revert the change you made.

Answer (score 1):

Just add these to your dependencies:

**firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1**

**firebase_messaging: ^13.0.4**

Then do:

**flutter pub get**

**flutter pub upgrade**

Answer (score 0):

solve my problem updating my firebase dependenceses

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It happens because you have upgraded the flutter SDK but not the associated packages which are compatible with it.
Go to "pub.dev" and update the versions in all the firebase products (e.g. firebase_core, firebase_auth, etc) to the latest available package.
Just updating the "firebase_core_platform_interface" might not solve future problems in production.

Answer (score 0):

Updating firebase packages to the latest versions solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade `firebase_core`, `firebase_storage`, `cloud_firestore`, `firebase_auth` etc. (firebase packages) one by one, by using the following command `flutter pub upgrade [package_name]`. Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is for the VS code . (4 March 2024)  Go at the Pubsec.yaml -> [image: click on the shown button] Click on the Shown button. You will see a details view of what version of pub packages can be update. Update accroding to it . For eg
if your Firebase_auth : &2.25.5 is this. Upgrade it to the latest version that showing in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

firebase_core: 2.2.0

work for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Changing the compileSdkVersion to 33 solved the issue for me,

In the `app/build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33 
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Keep it simple, just update the Firebase dependencies.
If you have multiple firebase dependencies you can do as follows

```yaml
firebase_crashlytics:
firebase_analytics:
firebase_core:
```

and then run

```
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).