# Why does adding 33 to compileSdkVersion give me this output?

Tags: flutter

/C:/flutter_windows_3.3.4-stable/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);

this appears when i execute my app

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74226250/error-member-not-found-firebaseappplatform-verifyextends)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your assist.
i was able to solve the error by using the necessary properties after i updated my packages/dependencies and it that  was fixed

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).