# My codes that worked fine 2 months ago are now giving an error

Tags: flutter, dart

My codes that worked fine 2 months ago are now giving an error. The error code is below. What should I do?

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
lib\main.dart:1
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.24.0/lib/src/firebase_app.dart:18:25: Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'.
    FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends(_delegate);
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
2

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1159

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 32s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)
```

Comment: Based on your error, the error is similar to  this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74226250/error-member-not-found-firebaseappplatform-verifyextends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your pubspec.yaml dependencies:

```
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
```

You can put it around `firebase_core` like so:

```
  firebase_core: ^1.21.0
  firebase_core_platform_interface: 4.5.1
```