# I am having trouble starting my flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle

I am new to flutter and I had this problem, I have seen everything but nothing has helped me. my project was working normally before but suddenly it started to give me some warnings in the console and it doesn't let me start my project.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOKM2.png)

if i upload the sdk version, it still won't let me start the project, attached is an image of my flutter doctor.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYIWs.png)

I need to fix this error as no one has been able to help me with this and I am at a standstill in relation to my work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Member not found: 'FirebaseAppPlatform.verifyExtends'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74226250/error-member-not-found-firebaseappplatform-verifyextends)

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you are using an old version of the `firebase_core` plugin. Your issue can be solved by updating to the latest version. Please refer to this link for more information: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9806.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar errors before, and often it is because of package updates. You should verify your pubspec.lock file. If you have your code in Github, you can check the changes to your file and then do a rollback if necessary, also can verify the versions of your dependencies inside that file. If that is the problem, you can hardcode your package versions in your pubspec.yaml file. I hope this helps. Feel free to leave a comment.